# PyQt 4 - QThread doesn't work?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have written an executable program. My idea is to load all data-items in a QTreeWidget at runtime. That is the reason why I want to use QThread. I don't want the GUI freezes while working with large data. But when I run this example program it freezes anyway. But why?

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialog, QProgressBar, QApplication, \
     QMessageBox, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem

class Test_Thread(QThread):
    notify_progress = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def create_items(self):
         for elem in xrange(190000):
             yield elem

    def run(self):
        for i in self.create_items():
            self.notify_progress.emit(str(i))

class MyCustomDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCustomDialog, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)

        self.pushButton_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton_close = QPushButton("Close", self)

        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_start)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_close)

        self.test_task = Test_Thread()
        self.test_task.notify_progress.connect(self.fill_tree_widget)

        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.pushButton_close.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def fill_tree_widget(self, i):
        parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        parent.setText(0, "Number: {}".format(i))
        parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | Qt.ItemIsTristate | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)

    def on_start(self):
        self.test_task.start()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyCustomDialog()
    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're not actually doing any time-consuming work in the thread, so it will make no difference. The things that take up the most time are all on the gui side, and they all have to happen in the main thread.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Can I get an example, please? So I can analyze it.

Comment: There's no way to make this work with multi-threading, because all the gui-related stuff has to happen in the main thread. The only way to solve this problem is to not load all the items at once. If the tree is deeply nested and with not too many top-level items, you can load more items whenever a parent item is expanded. But if there are lots of top-level items, you'll have to load the items in batches whenever the user scrolls further down. It's possible you could also get better performance using a custom model - but that may involve a lot more work. The first option is simplest.